# comiling error says "node undeclared" first use in program,although i made "node" a global one

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void print();
void insert(int);
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
struct node* head;
void insert(int x)
{
    struct node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data=x;
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
}
void print(void)
{
    struct node* temp=head;
    printf("the linked list is:\n");
    while(temp!=NULL)
         {
             printf("%d ",temp->data);
            temp=temp->next;

         }
         printf("\n");
}
main()
{
    head=NULL;
    printf("how many numbers?\n");
    int n,x,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("enter the number:\n");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        insert(x);
        print();
    }
return 0;
}
```

> comiling error says "node undeclared" first use in program,although i made "node" a global one
>   this code is just for creating a linked list and adding user  input values into the front of the linked list
>   insert(int x) function does the insertion work.

Comment: you don't have a global var `node`, only `head`

Comment: `struct node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));` --> `struct node* temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

Comment: Take care of `free`ing the `malloc`ated memory before the end of program..

Comment: a bit of vertical spacing, like around struct definitions, code blocks, function prototypes, etc would make the posted code massively easier to read.

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for the the `main()` function. (regardless of the poorly written microsoft C compiler allowing such errors) those two signatures are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int, char** )`   Strongly suggest using the appropriate signature

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code, never use tabs for indenting. Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful. (see the man page for `scanf()` to read the details

Comment: when declaring functions that do not take any parameters, the prototype for the function should have `void` between the parens.   The actual function declaration should NOT have the `void` between the parens

Comment: in C, when calling any of the memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) do not cast the returned value.  the returned value type is `void*` and can be assigned to any other pointer.  casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain  2) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: in the `insert()` function the expression: `sizeof(node)` is asking for the size of something that does not exist.  Perhaps you meant `sizeof( struct node)`

Comment: the file address space. I.E. outside of any function, is pre initialized as part of the program startup to all 0x00, so there is no need to have explicit code, like: `head=NULL'` in the `main()` function

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  Variable names like 'n', 'i', and 'x' are meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: the posted code fails to cleanup after it self, by passing all the allocated memory segments to `free()`.  The OS will normally cleanup after the program exits.  However, it is a very poor programming practice to have a program not clean up after itself.  And in long running or embedded programs this can lead to seg fault events as the available heap is consumed

Answer (score 4):

The error message is clear enough. In the function `insert` you should prepand the name `node` with the keyword `struct`.

```
void insert(int x)
{
    struct node* temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                       ^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^
```

Another way to escape the error is to use a typedef. For example

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node;
```

Comment: thanks,actually i am new to programming,i'll start adding free function in my future programs

Answer (score 3):

I presume when you say "first use" you mean the first line of `insert` where you try to allocate a node.  But it is not the first; outside of the definition, that is 3 lines above, where you declare `head` to be a `struct node*`.  (also note that *inside* the definition you use `struct node*` as well.)

The problem is that you did *not* define `node`; you defined `struct node`, and that is what you need to use.

Answer (score 2):

You might be confused by C++, in which a struct tag becomes a typedef. Try this:

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node;
```

Now you can just use `node` instead of `struct node` everywhere. Easier to read and easier to type.